# Stabilize voltage on 12VDC model train loco - both directions

Tags: electrolytic-capacitor, stabilizer

I am looking for a simple solution to stabilize the voltage on a 12VDC model train inside the loco, to overcome areas of bad contact on the track. For energy density I wanted to use electrolytic capacitors. But the solution should work in both driving directions...
I thought about just using a diode to charge one capactior by direction. But how can I get the energy back for the direction currently driving?

Comment: You're going to need to give us a lot more details if you want an answer. Most importantly, how does your model train work? In what way is the voltage currently unstable?

Comment: Sorry, I am so much into this that I forgot to explain about the basics. It is a H0 12VDC model train and I want to stabilize the driving voltage in the loco. It is hard to keep DC tracks clean and always ensure good contact from the track. So this is why I want to stabilize the voltage in the loco for smooth operation.

Comment: Okay, how does an H0 12VDC model train work, though?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean... There is -12V to +12V between the two rails of the track which controls speed and direction of the train... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HO_scale

Comment: I think what you are saying is that speed control is achieved by varying the DC voltage between -12 V (full-speed reverse) and +12 V (full-speed forward). You need to check this and give the datasheet of your controller. It might use PWM (pulse width modulation) where full 12 V pulses are applied to the track but with the pulse-width % on-time adjusted to give the required average voltage. Your capacitor solution may not work with this. Other solutions I've seen in the past apply high-frequency AC (current limited) superimposed on the DC to blast through the dirt on the track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a non-polar capacitor from two polar capacitors, like this (unfortunately it appears the schematic editor on this site doesn't have proper polar capacitor symbols)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjGULR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In transient operation, the first time the external voltage swings to a new higher voltage, one or the other diode conducts and charges the common node. The current drawn will be commensurate with the capacitor values shown.

The diodes prevent either capacitor from being too reverse biassed. As the input voltage swings either negative or positive, the rectification effect of the diodes pumps the common capacitor node to a higher positive voltage, biassing both capacitors properly. Schottky diodes will limit any transient reverse bias to a smaller voltage than silicon diodes. Most aluminium electrolytics will tolerate a transient reverse bias of less than a volt.

In normal operation, the effective capacitance is just the normal capacitor in series formula, so for the two 1000 uF caps here, it's effectively 500 uF. Both diodes will be reverse biassed, there will be no 'diode drops' in series with the 'non-polar capacitor'.

This sort of self-biassed arrangement will be fine for motor smoothing, but don't use it for audio as it is. For audio use, it would be advisable to bias the centre node with a large resistor to a voltage well above the expected applied swing, so the diodes would never conduct.

You will have a tradeoff with capacitor size, as you trade response time for degree of smoothing.

Comment: Okay, this looks like a simple solution! Thanks! With the only drawback of halving the capacitance... Could this be avoided by using some sort of transistor network to decide which capacitor being active based on the applied external voltage polarity?

Comment: @Reto It depends how complicated you want to go. You could rectify the rails into a single storage cap, then drive the motor from it with a FET H-bridge by sensing which rectifier diodes were conducting. You could plausibly get all of that stuff into less space than the second capacitor. It would have a voltage limit below which it wouldn't work well, unless you had a small control battery in there as well. Isn't the ability to control a train accurately at low speeds one of the touchstones of a good railway setup? With that lot, you might was well go DCC. Test the above first, it's simple.

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem with traditional model train setup is that the voltage across the tracks is used both to power the train as well as to tell it how fast to go and in which direction.

If you changed the way of controlling the train to something like [DCC (Digital Command Control)](https://www.nmra.org/beginners-guide-command-control-and-dcc) or radio control you could set the voltage across the tracks at a constant 12V in which case a capacitor might help you get you through rough spots on the track.

Comment: Yes of course this would be the best solution. But I do not want to change everything to DCC...

Comment: It is possible to use two capacitors, one for each polarity of supply, and to use diodes for current steering. The problem is that the motor voltage is reduced by two diode drops. If it is feasible to increase the track voltage to +/-14V,then this may provide an answer, but the two capacitors are bulky and anything else connected to the track might not appreciate the increase in voltage.

Comment: +/-14V is not a problem and already used now. Also voltage drop is not a problem either, this will just result in a lower speed. Looking forward to your idea.

Answer (score 0):

A simple DC power supply for a HO 12V DC model train would consist of a 12V transformer, rectifier and filter capacitor. Its voltage would be close to 17V DC  on no-load and could drop to 12V DC or lower depending on the load. Additional capacitors across its output would be of no use unless the existing ones have gone bad or are of inadequate capacity.

The solution would be to use a variable regulated DC power supply of adequate current rating in order that the set voltage is held irrespective of the load. Direction reversal could be achieved using a DPDT switch or relay.

In any case capacitors are not the solution for unclean wipers/tracks.

Comment: I am looking for a solution inside the loco. The voltage applied to the tracks is ok and needs no change. I used a capacitor inside the loco for testing and the results are great! But just going one direction. Wanting to go both directions makes the thing difficult.

Comment: It appears that you have connected the capacitor across the motor. The right way would be to connect it across the tracks or, in other words, across the output of the power supply.

Comment: No, the voltage on the track is ok. The problem is inside the loco when going over a switch

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in a previous comment: [image: Diode-steered capacitive smoothing]